# mongodb: How to create _id for each array element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a way that whenever I $push a new element in monodb array, a normal _id is added to it? I remember that mongoose was doing something like that automatically but now I am using mongodb's native js and it seems to be not inserting any _id.

Example:

```
chats.updateOne({_id: chat_id},
            {$push: {messages: 
                    {
                        message: data.message,
                        date: new Date(),
                    }}},
            function(err, response){}
)};
```

On executing, messages array should have regular _id field, message and date. Currently it only creates message and date.

Comment: You need to create schema for `messages`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

```
chats.updateOne({_id: chat_id},
            {$push: {messages: 
                    {
                        message: data.message,
                        date: new Date(),
                        _id: ObjectId()
                    }}},
            function(err, response){}
)};
```

Comment: ObjectId() is not the same function in NodeJS driver as in mongo Shell. Alternative is ObjectID.createFromTime(time). Just to help the future visitors. Docs: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#ObjectID.createFromTime